# How to implement simple N-dimensional vector in rust?

Tags: matrix, vector, rust

I am newbie to rust. I am trying to create an N-dimensional vector in rust. In that process, I wanted to write a function to get the dimensions of that vector. Below code is not giving what I expected. Any help will be appreciated.

```
use std::any::Any;

fn main() {
    let input = vec![
        [[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4]],
        [[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4]],
        [[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4]],
    ];

    let transformed_input = input.iter()
    .map(|x| x as &dyn Any)
    .collect::<Vec<&dyn Any>>();
    

    let matrix = Matrix::new(
        transformed_input,
    );
    println!("{:?}", matrix.dimensions());
}

trait MatrixElement {
    fn data(&self) {}
}

impl MatrixElement for isize {}
#[derive(Default, Debug)]
struct Matrix<'a> {
    data: Vec<&'a dyn Any>,
}

impl<'a> Matrix<'a> {
    fn new(data: Vec<&'a dyn Any>) -> Self {
        dbg!(&data);
        Self { data }
    }

    fn dimensions(&self) -> Vec<usize> {
        let mut out: Vec<usize> = vec![];
        let mut current_vec = self.data.clone();

        while let Some(first_child) = current_vec.first() {
            if let Some(vector) = first_child.downcast_ref::<Vec<&dyn Any>>() {
                //not coming in to this if condition
                out.push(vector.len());
                current_vec = vector.clone();
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
        out
    }
}
```

Here is the playground link:
https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=877e82f70b511a035664a938be88d981

Comment: Why did you decide that `Matrix::data`'s type should be `Vec<&'a dyn Any>`? Shouldn't this be `Vec<Vec<ME>>` where `ME: MatrixElement`?

Comment: @phimuemue I don't want to implement `MatrixElement` for every type I want to insert into `Matrix`. My naming convention as `Matrix` might be bad, but this matrix is not just for numbers.

Comment: But do you really want your matrix elements to be *dynamic* (i.e. do you want to add polymorphic stuff to your matrix)? Or are all elements *within one matrix* of same type? If so, could you make `Matrix` generic over the element type?

Comment: @phimuemue The problem I got while working with generics is downcasting. As you can see, `data` can contain Vec<Vec<Vec......Vec<T>>> or simply Vec<T>. Using `Any`, I am able to use `downcast_ref` on each iteration to check if its a `Vec` or not. If you can help me to downcast a generic without implementing `MatrixElement` trait for every possible type, it will help me a lot.

Comment: I think then you'd have to convert all the nesting levels to `&dyn Any`. That said, I do not think that this is the most straightforward approach to implement n-dimensional arrays. Maybe there are crates that could help you.

Comment: @krishna in my opinion it would be easier to keep a one-dimensional vector for data with a vector of dimensions' sizes. Dealing with `dyn Any` is fairly slow, assuming you'd like to run math on data later on

Comment: @AlexLarionov Can you please tell me the reason why the downcasting not working in above code?

Comment: Maybe it would be simpler to just keep a single `Vec<T>` containing all the elements, and a `Vec<usize>` containing all the dimensions?